# Generating HTML from a template on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I have an iPhone application which needs to generate a local HTML file from a template and then render the HTML in a UIWebView. It basically needs simple Django-like template features, just to replace template tags with values and simple enumeration over collections (for instance to generate rows of a table).  Is there some existing simple template framework available for iPhone apps (implemented in C or in Objective-C of course)?  I looked at Dashcode but that does not fit my needs I dont think.  I have an HTML file I just want to replace values in it and enumerate/loop over collections to do it.  I cant use Javascript for this actually because HTML needs to be email-able.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't follow exactly what your goal is, can you elaborate or explain step by step what it is you're looking to do?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [MGTemplateEngine](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/05/20/mgtemplateengine-templates-with-cocoa)

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/groue/GRMustache may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a simple tempalte class once.  It had `<%= foobar %>` style tags in it.  I would call `[myTemplate setValue:@"I like SO" forVar:@"foobar"]` which would find the tag and replace it.

Looping and enumeration might be much harder.  Maybe there is a ObjC templating library out there that I don't know of.